# Как сделать merge для одних и тех же файлов из разных проектов?

Tags: git, webstorm

Есть проект A, в котором есть файлы: file1, file2. Есть проект B с такими же файлами file1, file2, но с другим содержимым. Хочу соединить файлы: file1 проекта A с file1 проекта B и файл file2 соответственно. Как это можно сделать? (нужно сделать что-то типа ручного разрешения конфликтов)

Comment: а содержимое проекта идеологически совпадает то?

Comment: операция *merge* выполняется не для файлов, а для коммитов. вам, вероятно, поможет программа *diff*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно воспользоваться напрямую программой *diff*.

пример.

```
$ cat f1
1
2
3
$ cat f2
1
x
3
$ diff -u f1 f2
--- f1  2018-05-26 00:32:56.545662873 +0300
+++ f2  2018-05-26 00:33:13.369761319 +0300
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
 1
-2
+x
 3
```

если хотите, чтобы вывод выглядел «вроде ручного разрешения конфликтов»:

```
$ diff --changed-group-format="<<<<<<<%c'\012'%<=======%c'\012'%>>>>>>>>%c'\012'" f1 f2
1
<<<<<<<
2
=======
x
>>>>>>>
3
```